# Require attached file with column choice selection before saving record

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, attachments, custom-javascript

I have a custom list in SP13 with a choice column containing 'Yes', 'No', and 'NA' drop down values.  If the column value is marked 'Yes', I want to require the user to attach a related file to the record.

OOTB SP13
Choice type column is named Commercial Bus.
Drop-Down Menu choices are Yes, No, NA.
"Yes" requires a Commercial Bus Request Form be attached before the new (or edited) form can be saved.

I've seen one JQuery solution on here but from the post I an unable understand the JS syntax required for the script to recognize the column and option combination as a pre-save event. Could this be handled with column validation or is it strictly a JS solution.  Any help is creating a formula or JS solution that I can place into a script editor box on the list New Form and Edit Form aspx is greatly appreciated.

-Joe

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript.

1. Use F12 to get the id of "Commercial Bus" element

   [image]
2. Edit NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx, add a Script Editor web part and enter the following script to the web part.

Note: change "`Commercial_x0020_Bus_bc09f2d5-45a7-4255-8164-9f12207bf74f_$DropDownChoice`" to your's element id found in step 1.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function PreSaveAction() {
    var CommercialBusValue= document.getElementById("Commercial_x0020_Bus_bc09f2d5-45a7-4255-8164-9f12207bf74f_$DropDownChoice").value;
    var atch = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");
    if(CommercialBusValue == "Yes"){
        if (atch == null || atch.rows.length == 0)
        {
            alert("Documents attachment is required");
            return false ;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

3. Save the page.

After that, the item must has attachment(s) if user selects "yes". Otherwsise, he will get an alert and the item will not be saved.

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much for providing this.  If I may ask a follow up question:  How do I write in multiple elements

Comment: What do you mean by "write in multiple elements"?